# how to fit image inside circleAvatar

Tags: flutter

I was building a project and found a weird thing,, for the same piece of code the output was diff in 2 diff places :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFrGc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np9Vx.png)

The code i wrote :

```
CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
              'assets/images/profile.png',
            ),
            radius: 60.r,
          ),
```

any help guys ?

Comment: can you share the code for both the place with the parent widget. may be the parent widget size is small

Answer (score 0):

Use `child` instead of `backgroundImage` and it should scale accordingly:

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 60.r,
  child: Image.asset('assets/images/profile.png'),
),
```

You can also wrap `Image.asset` into a `Padding` widget to add some space:

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 60.r,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Image.asset('assets/images/profile.png'),
  ),
),
```